# is there any library that search for sentences that include a particular word

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, text-classification

I am trying to build a text classification model in Portuguese where it will be having 3 classes. to deal with negative cases I have also introduced 4th class as "irrelevant". Now based on high Frequency distribution, I want to get some meaningful sentences which includes a particular word   that serve purpose for negative case scenario.

I have tried nltk corpus from this url: https://www.nltk.org/howto/portuguese_en.html. but there are no matchings for certain words.so i am looking for better python library

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean that you have the text data and you need a library to search inside it? or that you're looking for a text corpus containing specific words? Text corpora are not necessarily packaged as python libraries. Btw the easiest to get some sentences containing specific words would be to run some google queries, it can be done through google API.

Comment: I don't have text data. But i need some language specific large corpus to search for sentences that should include a particular word.

Comment: Ok, then first it's important to understand that you need **text data**, not a software library. Very often large text data is called a **corpus** (plural *corpora*), you will find [lots of results with this term](https://www.google.com/search?q=portuguese+corpora). A popular method is often to [download the full content of Wikipedia](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/) in the target language.